# No source code is available for type java.util.Objects

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I've run into a pretty weird problem.
I checked out a repo from github in eclipse. It's a gwt project. When I try to compile the project, I got an error:
No source code is available for type java.util.Objects.
There are also some similar errors which all point to the same problem: I use the wrong Java version.
What is weird here is that I do use Java 7 in my project.
I can not post an image here but I do use java7. I added a test class which contains some features in java7, like switch(String), it works fine when I run it as a Java application.

Got a clue? Need help!

Answer: Thanks to sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ, I got it right. I used gwt-2.5.1. Change it to 2.6, it works! Thank you guys.

Comment: The question is correct.  There is no java.util.Object.  java.util.Objects is new since jdk 1.7

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ What do you mean? There's an java.utils.Objects in java7

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html

Comment: @curtisk Banging my head :P. :)

Comment: @OP As a side note, are you using GWT 2.6 ?? If No, then below 2.6 versions of GWT doesn't support java7.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ That's it! I used gwt2.5.1. After changing it to gwt sdk 2.6, it works! Thx a lot!

Comment: @StannisYoung Added my  answer :) Mark it as answer if it's useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If are you using GWT 2.6 , then below 2.6 versions of GWT doesn't support java7.

Java7 support added in GWT 2.6 version.

Make sure that the GWT version and Java version matching or not.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Eclipse couldn't find the java library.
Please check the project settings and source tab. and make sure that the java sdk was included.

Answer (score 0):

- Just because you have java 7, doesn't mean you have the source for it.
- Java code running in GWT is translated to Javascript, so some classes that work on a JVM won't work with GWT

Answer (score 0):

Check the JRE system library in project build path.
Right click on project -> Build Path -> Libraries

Also check for the java compiler compliance level
Right on project -> Properties -> Java Compiler